# LyX list of Alt-M shortcuts

Tags: lyx, shortcut

What does Alt+M then F or S or X or ... do? Is there a list of these shortcuts?

[image]

There's a partial list [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/FrequentlyUsedShortcuts) but I'm hoping to find a more complete list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Alt+m f"       "math-insert \frac"
"Alt+m s"       "math-insert \sqrt"
"Alt+m x"       "math-subscript"
"Alt+m e"       "math-superscript"

"Alt+m u"       "math-insert \sum"
"Alt+m i"       "math-insert \int"
"Alt+m m"       "math-mode" # produces mathematical text
"Alt+m d"       "math-display"

"Alt+m y"       "math-insert \oint"
"Alt+m p"       "math-insert \partial"
"Alt+m r"       "math-insert \root"
"Alt+m l"       "math-limits"
"Alt+m S-L l"   "math-limits limits"
"Alt+m S-L n"   "math-limits nolimits"
"Alt+m S-L space"   "math-limits empty"


"Alt+m n"       "math-number-toggle"
"Alt+m S-N"     "math-number-line-toggle"
"Alt+m 8"       "math-insert \infty"

"Alt+m o 1"     "self-insert \#1"
"Alt+m o 2"     "self-insert \#2"
"Alt+m o 3"     "self-insert \#3"
"Alt+m o 4"     "self-insert \#4"
"Alt+m o 5"     "self-insert \#5"
"Alt+m o 6"     "self-insert \#6"
"Alt+m o 7"     "self-insert \#7"
"Alt+m o 8"     "self-insert \#8"
"Alt+m o 9"     "self-insert \#9"

"Alt+m t n"     "math-mutate none"
"Alt+m t t"     "math-mutate dump"
"Alt+m t a"     "math-mutate align"
"Alt+m t i"     "math-mutate simple"
"Alt+m t d"     "math-mutate equation"
"Alt+m t e"     "math-mutate eqnarray"
"Alt+m t m"     "math-mutate multline"

"Alt+m c i"     "tabular-feature append-column"
"Alt+m c d"     "tabular-feature delete-column"
"Alt+m c c"     "tabular-feature copy-column"
"Alt+m c s"     "tabular-feature swap-column"
"Alt+m c a"     "tabular-feature add-vline-left"
"Alt+m c e"     "tabular-feature delete-vline-left"
"Alt+m c z"     "tabular-feature add-vline-right"
"Alt+m c x"     "tabular-feature delete-vline-right"

"Alt+m w i"     "tabular-feature append-row"
"Alt+m w d"     "tabular-feature delete-row"
"Alt+m w c"     "tabular-feature copy-row"
"Alt+m w s"     "tabular-feature swap-row"
"Alt+m w a"     "tabular-feature add-hline-above"
"Alt+m w e"     "tabular-feature delete-hline-above"
"Alt+m w z"     "tabular-feature add-hline-below"
"Alt+m w x"     "tabular-feature delete-hline-below"

"Alt+m w t"     "tabular-feature valign-top"
"Alt+m w m"     "tabular-feature valign-middle"
"Alt+m w b"     "tabular-feature valign-bottom"
"Alt+m c l"     "tabular-feature align-left"
"Alt+m c m"     "tabular-feature align-center"
"Alt+m c r"     "tabular-feature align-right"

"Alt+m ~S-quotedbl"     "math-insert \ddot"
"Alt+m h"           "math-insert \hat"
"Alt+m ~C-~M-~S-backslash"  "math-insert \grave"
"Alt+m ~S-slash"        "math-insert \acute"
"Alt+m ~C-~M-~S-ampersand"  "math-insert \tilde"
"Alt+m ~S-minus"        "math-insert \bar"
"Alt+m ~S-period"       "math-insert \dot"
"Alt+m S-V"         "math-insert \check"
"Alt+m S-U"         "math-insert \breve"
"Alt+m v"           "math-insert \vec"
"Alt+m ~S-underscore"   "math-insert \underbar"

"Alt+m b"           "math-insert \overline"
"Alt+m ~S-apostrophe"   "math-insert \prime"

# These do pairs of: () {} [] <> ||

"Alt+m ~S-parenleft"    "math-delim ( )"
"Alt+m ~C-~M-~S-bracketleft" "math-delim [ ]"
"Alt+m ~C-~M-~S-braceleft"  "math-delim { }"
"Alt+m ~S-less"     "math-delim langle rangle" # produces < >
"Alt+m ~S-greater"      "math-delim rangle langle" # produces > <
"Alt+m ~C-~M-~S-bar"    "math-delim | |"


"Alt+m ~S-plus" "math-insert \pm"
"Alt+m ~S-equal"    "math-insert \neq"

"Alt+m space"   "math-space"

"Alt+m g a"     "math-insert \alpha"
"Alt+m g b"     "math-insert \beta"
"Alt+m g c"     "math-insert \chi"
"Alt+m g d"     "math-insert \delta"
"Alt+m g e"     "math-insert \epsilon"
"Alt+m g f"     "math-insert \phi"
"Alt+m g g"     "math-insert \gamma"
"Alt+m g h"     "math-insert \eta"
"Alt+m g i"     "math-insert \iota"
"Alt+m g j"     "math-insert \varphi"
"Alt+m g k"     "math-insert \kappa"
"Alt+m g l"     "math-insert \lambda"
"Alt+m g m"     "math-insert \mu"
"Alt+m g n"     "math-insert \nu"
"Alt+m g o"     "math-insert \omega"
"Alt+m g p"     "math-insert \pi"
"Alt+m g q"     "math-insert \vartheta"
"Alt+m g r"     "math-insert \rho"
"Alt+m g s"     "math-insert \sigma"
"Alt+m g t"     "math-insert \tau"
"Alt+m g u"     "math-insert \upsilon"
"Alt+m g v"     "math-insert \theta"
"Alt+m g w"     "math-insert \omega"
"Alt+m g x"     "math-insert \xi"
"Alt+m g y"     "math-insert \psi"
"Alt+m g z"     "math-insert \zeta"

"Alt+m g S-D"   "math-insert \Delta"
"Alt+m g S-E"   "math-insert \varepsilon"
"Alt+m g S-F"   "math-insert \Phi"
"Alt+m g S-G"   "math-insert \Gamma"
"Alt+m g S-I"   "math-insert \iota"
"Alt+m g S-J"   "math-insert \epsilon"
"Alt+m g S-L"   "math-insert \Lambda"
"Alt+m g S-O"   "math-insert \Omega"
"Alt+m g S-P"   "math-insert \Pi"
"Alt+m g S-Q"   "math-insert \vartheta"
"Alt+m g S-R"   "math-insert \varrho"
"Alt+m g S-S"   "math-insert \Sigma"
"Alt+m g S-T"   "math-insert \varsigma"
"Alt+m g S-U"   "math-insert \Upsilon"
"Alt+m g S-V"   "math-insert \Theta"
"Alt+m g S-W"   "math-insert \Omega"
"Alt+m g S-X"   "math-insert \Xi"
"Alt+m g S-Y"   "math-insert \Psi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd>-><kbd>Preferences</kbd>-><kbd>Editing</kbd>-><kbd>Shortcuts</kbd>, In there you will find a list of all the shortcuts and their definition in terms of LFUNS (LyX functions).

To search shortcuts that  starts with the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, type `Alt+M` in the text field called `Show key-binding containing`.

A description of all LFUNS can be found at <kbd>Help</kbd>-><kbd>LyX Functions</kbd>.

You can also read about how to edit such key bindings in section c.2.2 of LyX's user's guide which you can access in <kbd>Help</kbd>-><kbd>User's Guide</kbd>

Comment: Is there a way to copy-paste this list of shortcuts as text to somewhere else?

Comment: LyX has two important directories, one that called library directory, and the other is usually referred as user directory. you can find their location at `Help->About LyX`. In the library directory open a folder called `bind`. There you will find a file called `cua.bind`, this is the default shortcuts file. Any modification you made yourself to the key bindings will be at the corresponding location at the user directory in a file called `user.bind`

Comment: Do not make any modifications to the files in the library directory, they will be erased when you update LyX, use the user directory for any custom changes you want to do.

Comment: @user24096 Sorry, forgot to tag you...

Comment: But cua.bind doesn't seem to contain all the shortcuts. If you can find the list of all the shortcuts, could you just copy-paste them here in your answer? Thanks

Comment: @user24096 Have a look at the end of `cua.bind`, It includes more files. I cannot list all the bindings in the post, this list is too long...

Comment: There's also Help > Shortcuts, but that list is not exhaustive.